# pointer being realloc'd was not allocated

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i,j;
    char takimlar[4][8]= { "TAKIM A ","TAKIM B","TAKIM C","TAKIM D"};
    char *var = malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    int sonuclar[4][4] = {
        {0,3,4,2},
        {1,2,3,1},
        {2,3,2,3},
        {0,2,1,4}
    };

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if (sonuclar[i][2]>sonuclar[i][3]) {
            var = realloc(var,8);
            for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
                var += takimlar[i][0];
            }
        }
        else if(sonuclar[i][2]<sonuclar[i][3]){
            var = realloc(var,8);
            for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
                var += takimlar[i][1];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s",var);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to dynamic allocate in memory for a variable and then I want to allocate more memory using realloc function. When I run this program I got this error:

> error for object 0x100100c17: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated.
>    set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

when I had a look in *`malloc.c`* file I saw these lines:

```
zone = find_registered_zone(old_ptr, &old_size);
    if (!zone) {
        malloc_printf("error for object %p: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated.\n"
        "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug\n", old_ptr);
        malloc_error_break();
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see your whole source code? The code you are showing is correct.

Comment: Did malloc initially return you a valid chunk of memory? realloc should work regardless, but I seem to recall that's a bit implementation dependant.

Comment: It's unlikely you're giving us the relevant code. Make a small, self-contained, complete example.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.sscce.org) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is incrementing the pointer `var`:

```
var += takimlar[i][0];
```

on subsequent iterations of the loop when `var` is passed to `realloc()` it is not a value returned by `realloc()` or `malloc()`. It *looks* as though the code is attempting to append a `char` to a `char*`, and this it not how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var += takimlar[i][0];
```

`var` is a `char*`, so you are adding a character to an address. I'm not sure it is what you want to do. Then, when you call `realloc`, the pointer isn't equal to the address returned by `malloc` anymore. Therefore you have a runtime error.